# Can connect to WiFi network from Windows but not from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

My laptop has a dual-boot setup, it runs Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.
I rent a room in a house and my landlord provides WiFi, and it works perfectly fine for the most part. I can use WiFi from Windows, from my phone, from another Macbook that I have, and other tenants also don't experience any issues.

But when I boot into Ubuntu, I can't connect to the same WiFi, it just keeps connecting forever until times out. I can connect to a mobile hotspot on my phone or other WiFi networks in other places.

I updated all the relevant drivers and packages, I tried rebooting network manager and the entire system, etc. One time I got it to connect and the internet worked! But after 5 minutes I got disconnected again (so it's definitely not a password issue).

I don't have any idea how to even start debugging this. Of course, the landlord says there's nothing weird about the WiFi setup. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: is the SSID showing? have you tried to select it and enter the password?

Comment: You mean, can I see the network? Yes, definitely. When I click on it, it just keeps "connecting..." forever